# php push to array from function

Tags: php, arrays, function, push

Nice day for all!

I need to fill the "global" array with other arrays. As an example, I wrote this function:

```
<?php
function f($ar=array(), $gl=array()){
    $gl[0]=array($ar[1]);
}
$globals=array();
$array_example=array('foo', 'bar');
f($array_example, $globals);
print_r($globals); //$globals is empty!
?>
```

Help me please. I can not understand why the var $globals is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: function f($ar=array(), &$gl=array()) --??

Comment: what do you need to do?

Comment: I need to fill the $globals array with values from other arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass the array [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) using `&`:

```
function f($ar = array(), &$gl = array())
{
    $gl[0] = array($ar[1]);
}

$globals = array();
$array_example = array('foo', 'bar');
f($array_example, $globals);
print_r($globals);
```

Will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/s8FUh)

Answer (score 0):

man first you should modify the `function` to return the value and assign the returned value for the value to be printed . 
you are print the `$global` and it is an empty `array` .
so your code should be like this .

```
<?php
    function f($ar = array(), $gl = array()){
        $gl[0] = array($ar[1]);
        return $gl;
    }
    $globals=array();
    $array_example=array('foo', 'bar');

    $globals = f($array_example, $globals);
    print_r($globals); 

    // prints out Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => bar ) )
?>
```

Comment: No sir. But each function call will fill the array with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Function always works on locally variables, And you want to use their locally variable scope to out of function.
Check with below code, I hope it will help you

```
function f($ar=array(), $gl=array()){
    return array($ar[1]);
}
$globals=array();
$array_example=array('foo', 'bar');
$tmpArray = f($array_example, $globals);
$globals[0]=$tmpArray;
print_r($globals);
```

Comment: Thank You :) But each event new index of $globals is unknown.

Comment: $array_example is getting data in loop from MySQL